# Two column inline form using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a budget template using Twitter Bootstrap.  The output should have a row label, two inline inputs, a totals output, two more inline inputs and a final totals output.  The idea is that each row would be one category, and the pair of inputs would be quantities and rates that, when multiplied, yield a total.  It would resemble the following:

```
Category_1     Input_1    Input_2   Total=Input_1*Input_2       Input_3    Input_4    Total=Input_3*Input_4
```

I'm having trouble putting all of this on one row using the class systems described in bootstrap.  I can get two inputs on the same line, but I don't know how to combine it with a non_input span in the middle followed by the last two inputs.  How might I do this?

**Update:**

I've gone through a few iterations to try this.  This is only the latest failed attempt:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <label class="control-label">Category 1</label>
    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder="Input 1">
    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder="Input 2">
    <label class="control-label">Total 1</label>
    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder="Input 3">
    <input class="span1" type="text" placeholder="Input 4">
    <label class="control-label">Total 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you ended up with?

Comment: I haven't really "ended up" with much of anything.  Everything I've tried has been a failure.  But will edit post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <span>Category 1</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Input 1">
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Input 2">
    <span>Total 1</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Input 3">
    <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Input 4">
    <span>Total 2</span>
</form>​
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8SMt/). Now you only nave to tweak spacing.

Also pay attention to the HTML elements you are using, label [should be associated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label) with a control.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use labels so I'd have the `for` attribute.  Notice I do NOT use the control-label class on the labels, otherwise things get messed up.  I find this to behave better when you have a narrow window or mobile since the label and input stay together and the two columns wrap first.

```
<div class="form-inline">
     <span style="margin-right:8px">
       <label for="IsPublic">Is Public:</label>
       <input id="IsPublic" .../>
     </span>
     <span>
       <label for="IsPrivate">Is Private:</label>
       <input id="IsPrivate" .../>
     </span>
</div>
```